# array displaying more results than normal

Tags: c++, arrays, binary, decimal

this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char character;
  int x;
  cout << "Input a character: " ;
  cin >> character;
  x = int(character);
  cout << "Its integer value is: " << x << endl;
  int arr[7], i=0,j;
  while(x>0)
  {
    arr[i]=x%2;
    i++;
    x=x/2;
  }
  cout << "Its Binary format is: ";
  for (j=i; j>=0;j--)
  {
    cout<<arr[j];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have only 8 array spaces allocated for this code but the displayed result is more than 8 and is totally unrelated to the algorithm. I'm suspecting this to be an overflow issue. 
How do i remedy this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: Using a debugger should be a good idea to find where your algo goes wrong

Comment: Also, give limits to your loop : are you sure that the first one doesn't make more thant 8 iterations ? and the second one ?

Comment: int arr[7] says seven, not eight.

Comment: @molbdnilo arr[7] means 8 places, from 0 to 7 (range `[0-7]`).

Comment: @Michael No, `arr[7]` means 7 places, indexed in the range [0-7) (that is, [0-6]).

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, right, I was making confusion.

Comment: thanks guys for the help!

Answer (score 5):

```
while(x>0)
{
    arr[i]=x%2;
    i++;
    x=x/2;
}
```

let's take case when this loop is executed once.
`i` is 1 after loop is finished. However, array element at index 1 is not initialized.

You trigger undefined behaviour by trying to print it here:

```
for (j=i; j>=0;j--) // assuming for should be here
{
    cout<<arr[j]; // access array element with index 1 (our example)
}
```

The fix is to change your loop to

```
for (j=i-1; j>=0;j--)
```

Also beware what if user enters number which is larger (or equal) than 7th power of 2. You won't have places in your array to store all digits. And will trigger again undefined behaviour, by trying to write past the end of the array.

Comment: Since with 7 bits, each one represented by a value in the array, we can represent numbers up to `2^7 - 1 = 128 - 1 = 127`, simply add a check when you convert the character into integer:
    
    `if (characther > 127 || character < 0)
       cout << "Error: invalid character." << endl;`